# What preposition does "congruent" take? "Congruent to" or "congruent with"?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, mathematics

On the internet I can find examples of both forms: "This triangle is congruent {to/with} that triangle", "this conclusion is congruent {to/with} the evidence".

Is there a correct form?

I'm specifically referring to the *mathematical* use of the word (["superposable so as to be coincident throughout"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/congruent), basically "the same shape and size") , but I assume the answer would apply for general use as well.

Comment: In my experience, two triangles are congruent. One triangle isn't congruent around/about/above another triangle. The whole set is congruent. I haven't done research to support this as an answer.

Comment: I think there's enough research shown in the question (now). Can it be unmark as "closed"?

Answer (score 4):

> In mathematics, this adjective can be used in phrases like "A and B are congruent", "A is congruent to B", and, less commonly, "A is congruent with B".

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/congruent) confirms the usage I am accustomed to: congruence is an equivalence relation, so the usage would be analogous to "equivalent (to)" (or "isomorphic (to)").

Answer (score 2):

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=congruent%20to%2Ccongruent%20with&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccongruent%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccongruent%20with%3B%2Cc0)***  shows "with" is the more common expression used with congruent.

***Congruent to*** is used in mathematics 
 meaning:

> - having the difference divisible by a given modulus:
>
>   - *12 is congruent to 2 (modulo 5) since 12−2=2·5*

or geometry, (of figures) identical in form; coinciding exactly when superimposed:

> - ‘*Each vertex triangle in the new hexagon is either congruent to one in the original hexagon or has the same base and height.’*

(M-W, ODO)